# goto(item) function for a jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, goto, coverflow

I'm building [this](http://demo.zdringhi.com/zdrcover/) plugin, which is 90% done, but I'm still having trouble and no ideas at this momemnt with a function that changes the current picture by clicking on a thumbnail item with its big picture.

The plugin is open source and you can find the code [here](https://github.com/TanaseButcaru/zdrcover).
The current state of the function only calculate where is the item that needs to be changed (on the left/right side of the current item) and calls prev/next function. This is the code (starting line 554):

```
 function goTo(item){
  var currentItem = getCurrent();

  if(item < currentItem){
   prev('goToCalled');
  }else if(item > currentItem){
   next('goToCalled');
  }
 };
```

I've tried to create a for loop that calls the prev/next function until the current item changes to the clicked one, but it's not working.

```
 ...
 if(item < currentItem){
   for(var i=0; i<currentitem-item;i++){
    prev('goToCalled');
 ...
```

Comment: I posted a link for the demo site and source code in my question. Here's the demo page: http://demo.zdringhi.com/zdrcover/ and the source code: https://github.com/TanaseButcaru/zdrcover

Comment: I'm thinking to copy the entire prev() & related functions inside the for loop and maybe that would do the trick. Just a thought..

Comment: Is an error occurring when you try to loop it as described? And to me it makes the most sense to have a `click` function for each thumbnail that passes the number of the name to the `goto` function. You could hard code it for each or iterate it using the same approach you used to get each number from the `name` attribute in your code

Comment: I don't get any errors when i try to loop it, the problem is that it loops just once and then nothing.
LE: i already have a `click` event for each thumbanil that passes the number to goto function:

`//For inactive items goTo() their big image
   $('.zdrth-current').not('.yes').parent().children('a').unbind('click').click(function(){
    //get item number
    var aname = $(this).attr('name');
    var anameArr = aname.split('-');

    goTo(anameArr[1]);
   });
`

Comment: If i copy all functions that are changing the item to the previous inside the for loop, i noticed that the bullet that show which element is active is changing correctly on every iteration, but the transition of the elements gets modified and everything happens in a few seconds, there's no smooth transition between items. 
Is there a way to make the loop to iterate after the transition inside it is complete?
EDIT: the bullet changes correctly only if i alert the number of iteration on every step.

Comment: [SOLVED] I've used `setTimeout(function(){ next/prev code}, transInt *i);` inside the for loop and everything works fine.